# bash NR with awk. How to print the rest of the lines?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm new on programming and I have a easy doubt but I do not find the answer to this in other questions...I hope you can help me :)

I have a file called `template.conf` and I need to make many ID.conf files changing two lines of that template (24 and 49). I have an idea of how to do it:

```
awk -v Id=${Id} '(NR==24){$3=${Id}".txt"} (NR==49){$3="Input_"${Id}".txt"}' \
  template.conf > ${Id}.conf
```

but this only prints row 24 and 49; not the rest of the template document...

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As written, that won't print anything.  You have to tell `awk` to actually print the lines.  Adding a `1` inside the quotes after the final `}` should do the trick.

Comment: Also you don't need the `()`s. Also `${Id}` is the field with value `Id`(likely a string so will default to 0). Vars in awk are just the name i.e `Id`

Comment: In awk you don't use `$` as a prefix for variables, so simply writing `Id` will expand to the value of the variable Id, eg. `awk -v Id="$id" '{$3=Id}1'` And `$` as prefix refers to a field, eg: `$1` refers to the value of the first field, or dynamic: `a=1;$(a)`

Comment: Thank you all! You help me a lot!! :)

Comment: The English word you want is `question`, not `doubt`, in this context - it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This awk should work.

```
awk -v Id=${Id} 'NR==24{$3=Id".txt"} NR==49{$3="Input_"Id".txt"}1' \
template.conf > ${Id}.conf
```

I guess the awk line is inside a bash script. The 1 at then end makes awk to print all lines.